# Background Mode in Ionic3

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have created a chat application in Ionic3 using socket.io. I am stuck in  a situation where the user sends a message when no network is available. Like in whatsapp it should automatically sent in background when the network is available. Is there any way to do it in Ionic3?

I have installed the plugin `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode` . Could you please help me how to do it in Ionic3?

Comment: Please help me with this feature

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the steps to resolve

1. import both network and background-mode plugin from ionic-native
2. Create listeners to watch the app network connectivity(Online and Offline).
3. Also create listeners to watch the app background mode (ON/OFF).
4. If app goes offline enable the background mode.
5. Inside background mode on event do your logic to save the data in localStorage or in indexDB whatever you preferred.
   for example:
   Push new message with message payload to array you defined.
   Then saved the array to indexDB.
6. If app get online, please check any data to sync or not inside the network on listener. Sync data background to server and clear the data from locally.
7. Also check the background mode is enabled, if it is already enabled please disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

U can use the background mode u install with this [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) from the docs.

u can use it as follow:

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

....

constructor(private network: Network) { }

....

let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network connected!');
  // YOUR LOGIC HERE
});
```